# Созданный файл используется другим процессом

Tags: c#, winforms

**Существует код:**

Его суть заключается в том, что он проверяет наличие файла и если файл существует, записать некоторые данные. А в случае, если файла не существует, то файл создается и после создания записываются в него некоторые данные.

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb"))
                        {
                            FileStream fs = File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
                            writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
                            writer.Close();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            FileStream fs = File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
                            writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
                            writer.Close();
                        }
```

**Проблема:**

Если файла не существует, то файл прекрасно себе создается, но туда не получается записать данные из за ошибки

---

System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "*Какой-нибудь очень длинный путь к файлу*", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

---

При этом, после перезапуска программы(файл-то уже создан) программа легко записывает некоторые данные.

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать так, что бы перед записью файл освободился от другого процесса и не нужно было бы перезапускать программу

Comment: Вам вот эта строка не о чем не говорит? `FileStream fs = File.Create(...`. Намекну - `Stream`. А вот эта? `File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");`. Короче говоря, `File.Create();` создает поток, который вы должны каким либо образом закрыть. Вы же создаете файл 2 раза, создавая тем самым два раза поток на один и тот же файл, вот он у вас и занят.

Comment: Вы два раза файл создать пытаетесь, еще и первый открытый фпйловый поток не закрываете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Спасибо ваш Комментарий вернул меня в реальность. Ошибку осознал

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю с ником EvgeniyZ

> Вам вот эта строка не о чем не говорит? FileStream fs = File.Create(.... Намекну - Stream. А вот эта? File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");. Короче говоря, File.Create(); создает поток, который вы должны каким либо образом закрыть. Вы же создаете файл 2 раза, создавая тем самым два раза поток на один и тот же файл, вот он у вас и занят. – EvgeniyZ

**Решение проблемы:**

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb"))
                        {

                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
                            writer.Close();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var myFile = File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            myFile.Close();

                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
                            writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
                            writer.Close();
                        }
```

В  таком виде все работает прекрасно

Comment: Для таких вещей придумали using

Comment: @Ivan, а больше ничего не смущает?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
> Thread.Sleep(1000);
> ```

Выкини это, оно вообще не нужно.

После этого ветви станут одинаковыми и if вообще не нужен.

> ```
> FileStream fs = File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb");
> StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
> writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
> writer.Close();
> ```

А это лучше заменить на

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb"))
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
```

или даже (насколько я помню, StreamWriter сам закрывает стрим):

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create("declor/log/poslog" + idt + ".possb")))
  writer.Write(DateTime.Now); //что-то пишем
```